# Spring environment cannot resolve placeholders

Tags: java, spring, properties

Using spring 3.2.5.
I have a web project with two application context (one parent of the other).

I configured, in xml, a placeholder configurer like this :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="WEB-INF/properties/*.properties, classpath:local.config.properties, file:${global.config.file}"
                              ignore-unresolvable="true"
                              ignore-resource-not-found="false"/>
```

The variable "global.config.file" is a path to a file specified in the JVM arguments passed to start tomcat.

In my code, I can successfully inject values from those files like this :

```
@Value("${blabla}")
private String blabla;
```

However, when I try to resolve place holders programmatically, via spring's Environment object, placeholders are not replaced with real values :

```
@Inject
Environment env;
// ...

public void test() {
  String blabla = env.resolvePlaceholders("${blabla}");
}
```

The blabla variables will contain it's unresolved value : "${blabla}"
Also, doing :

```
env.getProperty("blabla");
```

returns null.
Note that I'm using context schema location above 3.0 :

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
```

Can someone help me understand what I'm missing ?
Or any clue on how to debug further ?

Comment: There is nothing to debug as it works as designed. The registered `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` uses the environment to lookup properties it cannot find from the loaded files. It doesn't add the loaded properties to the `Environment` if you want that you need a `@Configuration` class and add a `@PropertySource` annotation as those are added to the `Environment`.

Comment: All you want is to be able to get the resource programatically? If that is the case, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265545/using-reloadableresourcebundlemessagesource-in-annotations-injection). I use it this way currently and it works for properties files.

Comment: Yes, I want to resolve string expressions using placeholders, at runtime.
M. Deinum : Does that mean that if I replace the namespace tag by manual definition of PropertySources, it will work ?  I need it to work in spring configuration files also.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `classpath*:`, for example:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:WEB-INF/properties/*.properties, classpath*:local.config.properties, file:${global.config.file}"
                          ignore-unresolvable="true"
                          ignore-resource-not-found="false"/>
```